# Android/Kotlin design pattern for sending from navbar to fragment to arbitrary fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewmodel

My navbar has a few buttons, and when the user starts the app they are presented with a tabbed view. Each of the tabs shows the same initial screen (tables with different data and columns), and the buttons in the navbar are to create a new record and search.

```
                  +-------------+
                  |MainViewModel|
                  +-------------+

                  +------------+
                  |MainActivity|
                  +------------+


+--------------+                     +--------------+
|AlphaViewModel|                     |BettaViewModel|
+--------------+                     +--------------+

+-------------+                      +-------------+
|AlphaFragment|                      |BettaFragment|
+-------------+                      +-------------+
```

Started working on a modal that opens when the user clicks the `+` navbar button, and I've hacked around [`Bundle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle) so now in this new `class CreateAnythingFragment: BottomSheetDialogFragment()` it knows the [`Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment) name and `action` (`+` in this circumstance). So I could pattern match on this with [`when`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression), and figure out how to send the data back to the fragment, dismiss the modal, and refresh the table.

But I feel like this pattern match shouldn't appear in `CreateAnythingFragment`, as that would couple it to known fragments only. So should I have some sort of global/root event stream that all the fragments subscribe to, and then in `CreateAnythingFragment` emit to that stream? - That seems really inefficient. Should I use [`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Intent)s?

What's the recommended approach here?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think this is what I was looking for https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#pass-between-fragments
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I feel like this whole problem would be better solved if you separated the concerns a little bit further.

Your "action" (to add X to "data X") should be abstracted away.

If I correctly understood your problem, you have a "common" method (in your "NavBar") to "add", but you need to know which fragment is visible to know which type of data to add to which table that is later shown in the correct fragment.

I feel this is a ViewModel's problem and then a Repository problem. You KNOW which fragment is visible, so you don't really need to worry too much about it; it should be each fragment's ultimate responsibility to signal the "add item" (via its viewModel) into a common repository where the new data is exposed as a `flow`, `liveData` or similar.

Each Fragment also "reads" (aka: observes) this stream of data, so if the fragment is started/visible/subscribed, it will listen to this common repo.

So to me, in my head, the solution consists of each viewModel having a "UseCase/Interactor/Behavior" (name it like you want) that knows what/how to insert.

Each fragment observes its viewModel for new data.

Each ViewModel talks to the "Things Repository" that you have (where each useCase inserts data).

All the Activity (and therefore its viewModel) have to do, is pass information to the existing fragment "hey, you have to insert data of your type", and then the fragment will know who to talk to (its viewModel) which will know what to do (insert it in the Things Repository).

I think you're trying to go against the Android Framework by taking a "shortcut" via Fragment -> Activity -> Fragment or even "Fragment <-> Fragment" when in truth, LiveData/LifeCycle aware streams of info would be in my opinion better suited.

Comment: I hear you, but in that circumstance I might as well just make a different create modal fragment for each kind of type I am `+`ing. The goal is to abstract it out so that the common code is all handled in one place, and all that the specialised fragments do is define custom XML and loads/stores/searches lists constructed from form data [and remote data]. Though most of that should be abstracted out also. Maybe they should just specify the schemas, and the rest can be handled at a higher level?

Comment: Yeah, I mean, you can always delegate further to have common code handle it. But the architecture doesn't mean there's no "abstraction". Each fragment/Viewmodel know about their own domain (or are "told" if you want to further abstract it), ultimately, an interface/contract defines how they talk to each other, so nothing stops your VM to call a "delegate/repository/etc" that does the work and returns a value.

Comment: You said... "in that circumstance I might as well just make a different create modal fragment for each kind of type I am +ing" but you already have different fragments (at least according to your image) "Alpha/Beta". I assumed you had different ones. In *any* case, your fragment can be the same, it's just a container to display a list of <T>. I think we're not talking about the same issue here. All your fragment needs is to know which "T" corresponds to its generic type. Am I missing something?

Comment: From a CRUD perspective, all 3 tabs have a: list screen, new record screen. Each refers to a different "entity". The `+` in the navbar launches the new record screen [modal] for the specific "entity" associated with currently active tab [fragment]. What's the DRY way of setting this up?

Comment: Let me get back to you, I have lots of ideas and I've done similar things in the past, but I'm busy at work atm. If I take too long and seems like I've forgotten, please ping me on this [chat room here on SO where I often hang out](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210228/android-help) and we can discuss what we both have in mind :)

Comment: Have you given this any further thought? - Really need some insight here…

Comment: Hey, Sorry for the super late reply, I have, but I got super busy and wasn't able to finish it. I still have the notes open in a text editor, I'll do my very best to help you this week.

Comment: So I came back to this, I'm struggling to understand your architecture, if the data is different (different columns, etc.) then you have different fragments. You also have different viewModels I suppose (since the data is different so are their requirements). Why do you consider this is "repeating" yourself? Each adapter has its own ViewHolders, so if you have 3 tabs, you have 3 recyclerViews, each with its own adapter. I had initially misunderstood you. If you want, come to the chat I linked above and let's discuss.